# Как получить случайные цифры от 5 до 8 на php?

Tags: php

Как получить случайные цифры на php, и чтобы кождый раз количество цифр была разной от 5 до 8 что-то вроде капчи например:

```
3 7 4 9 2
8 2 3 1 9 4 5 7
7 9 3 2 6 1
```

Comment: Хорошо бы все-таки для начала самостоятельно гуглить ответы на подобные вопросы.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вообще здесь нет ничего сложного, можно воспользоваться стандартной функцией [array_rand()](http://www.php.su/array_rand) в которую нужно всавити массив с цифрами и количество цифр для вывода

```
  <?php

        $min = 5;
        $max = 8;
        $count_arr = rand($min, $max);   
        $array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9);
        $random = array_rand($array,$count_arr); //$count_arr = количество цифр в массиве от 5 до 8   
        shuffle($random); //Перемешаем массив

     ?>


        <?php foreach ( $random as $value ): ?>

            <b><?php echo $value." " ; ?></b>

        <?php endforeach ;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$leng = rand(5, 8);
for ($i=0; $i < $leng; $i++) { 
    echo rand(1, 9) . ' ';
}
```

если я правильно понял диапазоны

Answer (score 1):

Это можно решить чуть более элегантно:

```
// Минимальное пятизначное число 10000, максимальное восьмизначное — 99999999.
$row = (string) rand(10000, 99999999);

// Если количество знаков тоже задаётся динамически:
$row = (string) rand(
    (integer) '1'.str_repeat('0', $min-1),
    (integer) str_repeat('9', $max)
);

// Далее для разбора, помимо substr() или mb_substr(),
// можно использовать и следующий синтаксис:

// Вариант №1:
$array = str_split($row, 1); // Разбиваем строку $row на элементы в массиве $array
                             // по одному символу в каждом из них

foreach ($array as $char) { // Потом обходим массив
    // И делаем что-нибудь с $char
}

// Вариант №2:
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($row); $i++) {
    $char = $row[$i]; // $row[$i] возвращает один символ строки,
                      // где $i — его порядковый номер.
}
```